# Unable to receive email from gmail on my VDS

Tags: email, email-bounces

I am using [`mailu`](https://mailu.io/) (docker mail server) as all-in-one mail server solution: pop3/imap/smtp with web-interface and so on. I can send emails from my vds to any other email and I can send email from one mailbox to another one using the same server (like, from `hello@example.com` to `bye@example.com`). However, when I send a text from `gmail` (or any other mail server outside my vds) my webserver is not contacted at all and I have "recipient not found" message then. This happens from time to time and I don't know the reason for it.
My domain is `example.co` and it has all needed records:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 example.co mx

; <<>> DiG 9.13.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 example.co mx
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45588
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.co.          IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.co.       1799    IN  MX  0 example.co.
example.co.       1799    IN  MX  10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
example.co.       1799    IN  MX  1 smtp.secureserver.net.

;; Query time: 66 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 27 18:34:54 MSK 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

And the domain is accessible of course. But sometimes (and now also) other mail servers can't reach mine:

If I [test](https://www.verifyemailaddress.org/) my mailbox (for example, `noreply@example.co`) the service says:

```
X record found: example.co (Priority 0)
MX record found: smtp.secureserver.net (Priority 1)
MX record found: mailstore1.secureserver.net (Priority 10)
Connecting to example.co
Connect to example.co failed
Connecting to smtp.secureserver.net
Connected to smtp.secureserver.net
Dialog with smtp.secureserver.net ok
------------------------------------------------------------
220 p3plibsmtp01-08.prod.phx3.secureserver.net bizsmtp ESMTP server ready
HELO verifyemailaddress.org
250 p3plibsmtp01-08.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [209.126.119.123], pleased to meet you
MAIL FROM: <noreply@verifyemailaddress.org>
250 2.1.0 <noreply@verifyemailaddress.org> sender ok
RCPT TO: <noreply@example.co>
550 5.1.1 <noreply@example.co> Recipient not found. <http://x.co/irbounce>
QUIT
221 2.0.0 p3plibsmtp01-08.prod.phx3.secureserver.net bizsmtp closing connection
------------------------------------------------------------
Email address noreply@example.co rejected
```

I have no idea why anyone can't connect to my server but If I try to see whether I have opened ports or not, I see they actually are opened:

```
$ nmap example.co
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-10-27 18:48 MSK
Nmap scan report for  .co (185.246.155.33)
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp    filtered smtp
465/tcp   open     smtps
587/tcp   open     submission
993/tcp   open     imaps
995/tcp   open     pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.87 seconds
```

Interesting thing that from my home pc I see that `25/tcp` is opened and filtered but I can't see it from `nmap`'s output on my VDS (where it comes from)? If I `telnet` these ports, all of them are opened successfully.

I don't expose `25` port for `mailu` from the docker container, probably, this is the reason for the problem.

UPD: I have opened `25` port for `mailu` and now `gmail` sends email successfully and I receive it on my side. Why was it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple MX records. One points to your mail server, the other two point to GoDaddy's mail servers.

Your mail server test at verifyemailaddress.org went to GoDaddy's mail servers, not your own, because you didn't have port 25 open, and thus your MX record could not be used.

It's not clear why you have MX records pointing to GoDaddy if you are hosting your mail yourself.

You should remove the MX records which point to the wrong mail servers.